# In MV* patterns, what exactly is the model?

Tags: design-patterns, model-view-controller, mvvm, model

In MV* patterns, what exactly is the Model which stands for "M"?
Is it a POCO? or is it a class that contains your all bulky and reusable business logic?

I read a lot on web (and SO) but the terms are really confusing.
Some say model should be bulky which points to the entire reusable business logic.
Some say it is your data model which points to the POCO which is replica of your table and its fields.

If it is POCO then how it could be bulky and where should your business logic go?

I have implemented MVC in couple of the projects where my Model is NOT a POCO; it contains reusable business logic. I hope I done it right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the definition of MV*, Model is responsible for proceeding business logic and managing data. Depending on developer experience, the Model can exist in different forms. For example: Services + POCOs or Services + Domain Models + Strategies or else. Some developers prefer putting all business logic inside services, following Anemic Domain Model. Other prefer keeping logic in Domain Model as much as possible and only introducing services for the logic that involves multiple Domain Models.

I had some open talks with PHP developers and they said MVC has two 'variants': Fat Controller-Thin Model and Fat Model-Thin Controller, in which the fat one proceeds business logic. But I don't see Fat Controller-Thin Model is actually a variant because placing biz logic inside Controller makes your business logic less re-usable and against Single Responsibility Principle.

Comment: **the Model can exist in different forms. For example: Services + POCOs or Services + Domain Models + Strategies or else** this clears most of my doubts.

Comment: So can I say my model consists of BL + POCOs?

Comment: Yes, although the seperation of the business logic from the (then anemic) domain model is considered an anti-pattern (bad practice). Services should only contain transactional code, not the whole business logic.